# R - Difference in subsetting with `subset()` vs. brackets [ ]?

Tags: subset, slice

Why might I come up with very different answers for these two lines of code:

```
    nrow(aql[(aql$`Land Use`=="RESIDENTIAL" & aql$`Location Setting`=="SUBURBAN"),])
[1] 4514
```

...and...

```
    nrow(subset(aql, (`Location Setting`=="SUBURBAN" & `Land Use`=="RESIDENTIAL")))
[1] 3527
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full data, but there are a few unusual instances where things might get messed up when using `subset()` instead of brackets. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without a more reproducible example, but it is likely the influence of `NA` values in the `Location Setting` or `Land Use` variables.

The `subset` function explicitly strips them out, while `[` does not.

R does some unintuitive things when comparing `NA` and `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, so be careful for something like this:

```
NA & FALSE
```

[1]   FALSE

```
NA & TRUE
```

[1] NA

Comment: It is intuitive if you consider `NA` as a true or false value. `NA & FALSE` will always be false, but we are not sure about `NA & TRUE`.